# Async Loading UserControls in ItemControl WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, data-binding, user-controls

I would like to print the movie information from the tmdb api and print the movie information into the usercontrols. I want the program to show a poster, its name, its release date, how many votes and so on. My problem starts right here, I want to load usercontrolls as async, so I want all of them loaded in my main window at the same time. But I can't do it, they're loading one by one. Is there a way to use Async in the UI update? Or is there another way to achieve this? I want to get the names of all 20 movie posters at the same time as the webpages and get these 20 usercontrol added to my main window at the same time. I am using this code right now:

```
private async  void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
          await  GetPopularMoviesAsync();


        }

        public async Task GetPopularMoviesAsync()
        {
             SearchContainer<SearchMovie> popularMovies = await client.GetMoviePopularListAsync("en", 1);
              List<SearchMovie> popularMovieList = popularMovies.Results;
              foreach (var searchMovie in popularMovieList)
              {
                  MovieUSC mov = new MovieUSC();
                  var image = await GetMovieImage(searchMovie);
                  GetPosterFromFile(image, mov.MoviePoster);

                  mov.Name = "PopularMovies" + searchMovie.Id;
                  mov.MovieName.Text = searchMovie.OriginalTitle;

                  mov.MovieReleaseDate.Text = "(" + searchMovie.ReleaseDate.Value.Year + ")";
                  mov.MovieRatingBar.Value = Convert.ToInt32(searchMovie.VoteAverage) / 2;
                  mov.ClickedMovie += ClickedMovie;
                  MoviePanel.Items.Add(mov);

              }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if you don't want to go the whole MVVM route, it's still good practice to separate data access from the UI.

Use an ObservableCollection<> to hold the search results, which will be the driver of the display - this will automatically update any bound controls each time it is refreshed.

```
public ObservableCollection<SearchMovie> PopularMovies { get; } 
    = new public ObservableCollection<SearchMovie>(); 

private async void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var popularMovies = await client.GetMoviePopularListAsync("en", 1);

    PopularMovies.Clear();
    foreach(var movie in popularMovies)
        PopularMovies.Add(movie); 
}
```

Your window should use either a `ListBox` if you want the user to be able to select a specific movie item, otherwise an `ItemsControl`. In either case, set `ItemsSource` to the PopularMovies collection. Use a `DataTemplate` to define the layout for each movie item - each control is bound to the appropriate property of the SearchMovie object.

```
<ItemsContol x:Name="MoviesDisplay">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
             <StackPanel>
                  <TextBlock Text="{Binding OriginalTitle}" />
                  <TextBlock Text="{Binding ReleaseDate.Value.Year}" />

                  // Add more controls here as required
             </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate> 
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Can I use UserControls for binding movie details ?

Comment: I can distinguish which movie the user pressed with the movie id in the UserControl name. Like "PopularMovies" + searchMovie.Id

Comment: It feels like you're trying to clone a Winforms application (or methodology) into WPF. What can a user control do that you can't do much easier with DataTemplates / binding in WPF?

Comment: Ok I get it what you are saying But How can I design ItemsControl items like that: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhE7a.gif

Comment: You would need to set the ItemPanelTemplate of the ItemsControl - see https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/list-controls/itemscontrol/ for an example. The DataTemplate would then contain the Image control and any others that you require.

Comment: Yes. You can use a wrappanel as the itemspanel in the itemscontrol and you can use pretty much anything as what is templated out for each item. A flavour https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/33327.wpf-wrappanel-itemspanel-last-of-line.aspx

Comment: <TextBlock Text="{Binding OriginalTitle}" />
How can I access this from C# code to change visibility ?